# rmarkdown linked cross-references at word

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

In word I can link a figure using the cross reference menu so when I see the figure's name in the text I just click on it and this takes me in the page with the actual figure.

However, as I'm using rmarkdown to generate the report using `bookdown::word_document2` I would like to have these cross links ready made. But when I knit the document the corss references menu is empty. So I have to make it manualy which makes it waste of time using the `\@ref` on bookdown.

Is there a way to produce a word file with the cross references already linked?

[image]

The code for the word showing in the picture is here,

````
---
title: Cross-referencing figures, tables, and equations
author: Generated by bookdown
output:
  bookdown::word_document2: 
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 4
    fig_caption: yes
    number_sections: yes
---

See Figure \@ref(fig:cars-plot).

```{r cars-plot, fig.cap="The cars data.", echo=FALSE}
par(mar = c(4, 4, .2, .1))
plot(cars)  # a scatterplot
```

Also see Equation \@ref(eq:mean).

\begin{equation}
\bar{X} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{n} (\#eq:mean)
\end{equation}

And see Table \@ref(tab:mtcars).

```{r mtcars, echo=FALSE}
knitr::kable(mtcars[1:5, 1:5], caption = "The mtcars data.")
```
````

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing, pandoc, R Markdown, Bookdown, and Quarto does **NOT** support Microsoft Word native cross references.